# Why is the variable not being passed from the data layer to Google Analytics in the right format?

Tags: variables, analytics, layer

I am sending "User ID" as a string via data layer using Google Tag Manager to Google Analytics.

In the DataLayer the Userid:"0x91511bb4502B7F01539EB91AC8F35c9F7a16b0dB".
But on Google Analytics the variable is displayed as UserID: 8.29612e+47

Here is the DataLayer code:

```
dataLayer: {
event: "UserID"
user_id: "0x91511bb4502B7F01539EB91AC8F35c9F7a16b0dB"
}
```

But on Google Analytics, instead of seeing "0x91511bb4502B7F01539EB91AC8F35c9F7a16b0dB" as UserID, I only see o8.29612e+47. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

0x indicates it's a hexidecimal. Looks like someone at some stage converts it to decimal.

First of all, 0x part is not useful for the user id, so I would recommend removing it.

Next, you want to debug it properly. Inspect your network request and see if the user id is passed as a hex, or a decimal to GA.

If it's passed as a decimal number to GA, then your issue is somewhere in GTM. If it's passed as a 0x string, then removing 0x should stop GA from automapping a hex into a decimal.

I would also take a look at how that decimal is being passed. Json 5 supports   hex numbers in exactly your format. In that case, just adding quotes around the number will likely solve the issue.

It looks like GA does the conversion. I wouldn't expect GA to do it. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I will try to remove the 0x and see. 

The GTM is passing them as an exact string. It's GA that is doing the conversion. And I don't have any options to change it's formats.

Comment: and it's GA4 we're talking about?

Comment: Yes, I am using GA4.

Comment: Yeah, Google pretends like it's good enough to be in prod, while it has lots of severe issues. A public beta, basically. But yes, let us know if removing 0x prevents it from reformatting the string.